# Restart Hyper V machine using powershell cmdlet from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to build an app to restart VMs in Hyper V in Server 2012 
I had each VM in the list restarting but i want to adapt it to turn the machine off and then back on. The commented code is the working forced resart. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public async static void RestartAllVMs(List<VM> vmList, int timeDelay)
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        foreach (VM vm in vmList)
        {
            /*//Create PowerShell object
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddCommand("Restart-VM");
            ps.AddArgument(vm.vmName);
            ps.AddParameter("Force");
            ps.Invoke();
            await Task.Delay(timeDelay * 1000);*/

            //Create PowerShell object
            //I want to run from here down instead of just restarting the code doesn't work and no errors are thrown.
            ps.AddCommand("Stop-VM");
            ps.AddArgument(vm.vmName);
            ps.AddCommand("Start-Sleep");
            ps.AddParameter("s", 10);



            ps.AddCommand("Start-VM");
            ps.AddArgument(vm.vmName);
            ps.AddCommand("Start-Sleep");
            ps.AddParameter("m", 500);
            ps.Invoke();
            await Task.Delay(timeDelay * 1000);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: That's still not a question. and if you have more info, please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: from the Stop vm cmd, no errors are thrown, the resart cmd sequence in the commented code does work. however i want to use the sequence from the stop vm cmd

Comment: Doesn't the `Stop-VM` command need a `-name` argument? Something like `Stop-VM -name SomeComputer`?

Comment: The arguement is given by the AddArguement(vm.vmName)

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it be `AddParameter("Name", vm.vmName)`?

Comment: It does seem to work in the commented restart code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you still need an answer:

```
using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
```

before you start

```
shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName "name of your target PC" -ScriptBlock {Stop-VM " + VM.getname() + "}");
```

Stopps the VM and waits for result

```
shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName "name of your target PC" -ScriptBlock {Start-VM " + VM.getname() + "}");
```

Starts the VM and waits for result

```
foreach (PSObject outputItem in shell.Invoke())
{
    string name = outputItem.Members["Name"].Value.ToString()
}
```

Runs through all Machines and returns in this case the Name of your machine into string name, but it can return every parameter of the engine. (in this case string will only have the name of the last machine because it gets constantly rewritten but it should be no problem to replace it with your containing object.)

```
shell.Streams.Error
shell.Streams.Warning
```

returning all problems from powershell.

Hope that helps.

PS: Make sure that you have an up to date powershell, since many systems have older ones, that don't support all the commands, Also maybe there is an restart command, but I don't know and since I can't test it where I am, you need to find that for yourself.