# How to delete hyper-v VM using C# WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to automate hyper-v vm operations using c# and WMI. Able to change VM state. Now I need to delete VM using C# and WMI and [Msvm_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723874(v=vs.85).aspx) has only one method RequestStateChange. Is there any way to perform this action on VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `DestroyVirtualSystem` method of the `Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService` class. You can look at its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136790(v=vs.85).aspx) or check out a [sample script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9d97520d-d575-4dc2-9d31-e9e62b0ff562) (it's in VBScript but you should be able to translate it to C# fairly easily).

Note that the [Hyper-V PowerShell cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/hyper-v/hyper-v) are incredibly rich and can be invoked with a PowerShell script or from C# - see [example 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac09f0ce-a41f-4f37-966f-a8747f26d903/how-to-execute-hyperv-cmdlets-powershell-windows-server-2012-using-vs2010-c?forum=csharpgeneral) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839993/restart-hyper-v-machine-using-powershell-cmdlet-from-c-sharp). You can consider using them too.